# Arraylist in C holding strings

Tags: c, string, arraylist

I am trying to implement an arraylist in C that holds strings as elements. Here is what I have so far:

```
typedef struct ArrayList {
  int length;
  int capacity;
  char *items;
} ArrayList;


ArrayList *newList() {
  char *items = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
  ArrayList *list = malloc(sizeof(ArrayList));
  list->length = 0;
  list->capacity = 4;
  list->items = items;
  return list;
}

// Check and expand list if needed
void check(ArrayList *list) {
  if (list->length >= list->capacity) {
    list->capacity = list->capacity * 2;
    list->items = realloc(list->items, list->capacity * sizeof(char));
    if (list->items == NULL) {
      exit(1);
    }
  }
}

void add(ArrayList *list, char *s) {
  check(list);
  list->items[list->length] = s;
  list->length++;
}
```

However, when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]. 
list->items[list->length] = s;
```

Comment: why do you assign `s` (which is a `char[]`) to `list->items` (a `int*`)?

Comment: I edited my struct code so that list->items is a char pointer.

Comment: If you want to store multiple strings then `char *items;` --> `char **items;` and a number of related changes. You also need memory for the strings (unless you only store string literals)

Comment: Your code as it stands here tries to an "arraylist" holding _characters_, not strings.

Comment: I am new to C, how would I hold strings instead of characters?

Comment: @GabbyHan as a matter of fact a String is nothing but an array of characters.

Comment: In your newList func you make the capacity 4 and the length 0 why? Doesn't length reffer to the number of characters for each string? And capacity reffers to the number of strings in the list?

Comment: @Kozmotronik no, the length is the actual length, the capacity is the maximal length that can be stored before `realloc` needs to be called. This is a very common pattern

Answer (score 2):

Since a string is an array of characters, the `ArrayList.items` should be an array of pointers to arrays of characters. The function `check()` must check and, if necessary, expand the capacity of this array of pointers. The function `add()` must allocate space for the new string depending on its size.

All in all, the modified code could be as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ArrayList {
  int length;
  int capacity;
  char **items;
} ArrayList;


ArrayList *newList(void) {
  char **items = malloc(4 * sizeof(char *));
  ArrayList *list = malloc(sizeof(ArrayList));
  list->length = 0;
  list->capacity = 4;
  list->items = items;
  return list;
}

// Check and expand list if needed
void check(ArrayList *list) {
  if (list->length >= list->capacity) {
    list->capacity = list->capacity * 2;
    list->items = realloc(list->items, list->capacity * sizeof(char *));
    if (list->items == NULL) {
      exit(1);
    }
  }
}

void add(ArrayList *list, const char *s) {
  check(list);
  list->items[list->length] = malloc(strlen(s)+1);
  strcpy(list->items[list->length], s);
  list->length++;
}
```